# Suddenly nginx throws permission denied

Tags: docker, nginx

We have an nginx running in a docker (docker image nginx:1.19.2-perl). In principle, permissions are correct everything works fine when we start but then after sometime (maybe hours or days), suddenly users gets a forbidden 403 when accessing couple of files. And in the nginx logs we see a permission error. This seems to happen always over the same two files. But again, it does not happen always, after a restart it works fine again.

```
[error] 16#16: *101701 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/plugins/jquery.easy-pie-chart/dist/jquery.easypiechart.js" failed (13: Permission denied), client: xxxx, server: xxx, request: "GET /plugins/jquery.easy-pie-chart/dist/jquery.easypiechart.js HTTP/1.1", host: "yyyy", referrer: "http://xxxx/"
[error] 16#16: *101702 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/plugins/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.js" failed (13: Permission denied), client: xxx, server: yyy, request: "GET /plugins/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.js HTTP/1.1", host: "xxx", referrer: "http://xxx/"
```

Any idea what might be happening?.

We did not see this issue before updating nxginx (previous version nginx:1.12.0-perl) and before udpating host OS (before Ubuntu 16.04.3 now Ubuntu 16.04.6)

Edit:
Another mystery, if we do an 'ls' of the directory where the file is located the problem is solved, until the error happens again in few hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case my previous answer doesn't work you can try loading the scrips via CDN instead of from your filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be related with some missing config in you Dockerfile. Try adding this to your Dockerfile:

```
RUN chgrp -R root /var/cache/nginx /var/run /var/log/nginx && \
    chmod -R 770 /var/cache/nginx /var/run /var/log/nginx
```